# VBA: Create a csv from an excel file xlsm/xlsx

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm using a code below to change an xlsm file into a csv . The goal is to concatenate the columns cells in the first column for each row:  So it works in a certain way but for some rows, the final csv doesn't concatenate all the cells  for the same row, I have 2 columns filled instead of only the first. Does anybody have another algo that concatenate each cells for the same row into the first cell and separate them by a ";" even if there is some text with comma into certain cells at first ?

example of a cell:

```
ID   Provider          Rationale
4    mister provider   the rationale describe an id, and there is some comma in it.
```

Example of expected output:

```
id;Provider;Rationale
4;mister provider;therationale describe an id; and there is some comma in it
```

```
    Dim Fe As Worksheet
    Dim Plage As Range
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim Tbl() As String
    Dim Ligne As String
    Dim Dossier As String
    Dim Chemin As String
    Dim Fichier As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dossier = "C:\my_path"

    Fichier = "My_Name " & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".csv"

    'full path
    Chemin = Dossier & Fichier

    Set Fe = Worksheets("Upload")

    Set Plage = DefPlage(Fe, 1, 1)

    For i = 1 To Plage.Rows.Count

        For j = 1 To Plage.Columns.Count: Ligne = Ligne & Plage(i, j).Value & ",": Next j

        'delete the ; at the end
        Ligne = Left(Ligne, Len(Ligne) - 1)

        'store in a table
        ReDim Preserve Tbl(1 To i)
        Tbl(i) = Ligne

        'For the next on
        Ligne = ""

    Next i

    'create .csv file
    Open Chemin For Output As #1

        For i = 1 To UBound(Tbl): Print #1, Tbl(i): Next i

    Close #1

Function DefPlage(Fe As Worksheet, L As Long, C As Long) As Range

    On Error GoTo Fin

    With Fe

        Set DefPlage = .Range(.Cells(L, C), _
                       .Cells(.Cells.Find("*", .[A1], -4123, , _
                       1, 2).Row, .Cells.Find("*", .[A1], -4123, , _
                       2, 2).Column))

    End With

    Exit Function

Fin:

    Set DefPlage = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Why if you want to concatenate with `;` do you have `,` in `Ligne = Ligne & Plage(i, j).Value & ",":` ? Is `DefPlage()` a function not shown ?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I added the DefPlage() function. With ";" instead of "," it actually gives me a csv but "excel format" style with separate columns and still my last input column that ends up cut in several columns at the end of my output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the text has a separator, in this case is the “,”. You must put some escape char to not count as a separator. If the csv will be open with excel, put all text between quotation marks (“).

Example, change the line that concatenates the string:

```
For j = 1 To Plage.Columns.Count: Ligne = Ligne & """" & Plage(i, j).Value & """;": Next j
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Ultimately, the best way to create a new csv is to simply open a new csv blank, loop through each line and column of your input file and paste within the first column of the output blank csv file. However, I'm blocking on one line to get the last used column for each row:

    Dim lColumn As Long
    lColumn = shtUpload.Cells(nRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column